# why begintime in alarm should not be DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, alarm

I had an exception while doing an app using alarm but unfortunately I had an exception knowing no answer for it.

```
alarm = new Alarm(TitleBox.Text);
//alarm.BeginTime = DateTime.Now;
alarm.BeginTime=DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
alarm.Content = "Alarm scheduled for a note.Please check it right now.";
alarm.ExpirationTime = expiryTime;
alarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
IsAlaramOn = true;
ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
```

Why does an exception occur when the begin time is DateTime.Now?
Why do I need to add few seconds?

Comment: What language is this? It looks familiar...

Comment: i did the coding in c#

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought it looked like a C-based language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not heavily familiar with Windows Phone 7 development, I would think that, logically, alarm would not accept the current time because the time it takes for the code to run would move the current time past the alarm time, even by a few milliseconds.

If you think about it, computers think in milliseconds since epoch, not in hours/minutes/seconds. So, even if a single millisecond passes since the alarm was set to "now", the alarm is past due.

The Microsoft developers, then, would have set up the Alarm class to throw an exception for an alarm set for "now", because of that discrepancy, probably because an alarm would not fire retroactively. (If it DID fire retroactively, then they'd have to provide further for determining under what conditions it would do so, for very little benefit.)

Again, though, I'm not heavily familiar with the Windows Phone 7 platform, so if anyone has information to the contrary, please contribute!

Comment: Exactly, Alarms are for future events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BeginTime property is to say when the alarm should ring and hence i couldnt make it the current time.